# I got OverconstrainedError only Firefox on Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, firefox, webrtc

here is my code

```js
const userVideo = document.getElementById("user-video");

const CONSTRAINTS = {
  audio: {
    autoGainControl: false,
    channelCount: 2,
    echoCancellation: true,
    noiseSuppression: true,
    sampleRate: 48000,
    sampleSize: 16,
  },
  video: {
    facingMode: "user",
    width: { min: 0, ideal: 320, max: 320 },
    height: { min: 0, ideal: 240, max: 240 },
    frameRate: { ideal: 15, max: 30 },
  },
};

(async () => {
  const userMedia = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(CONSTRAINTS);
  console.log(userMedia);

  userVideo.srcObject = userMedia;
})();
```

It is working fine on Chrome and Safari
BUT in Firefox I got an error `OverconstrainedError`

```
MediaStreamError
constraint: "width"
message: "Constraints could be not satisfied."​
name: "OverconstrainedError"
stack: ""
```

So I try to change `width` and `height` constraints to

```
width: { min: 0, ideal: 320, max: 360 },
height: { min: 0, ideal: 240, max: 300 },
```

IT'S WORKING FINE!!!!

Ps. I tested WebRTC on this website https://test.webrtc.org/
Firefox on MacBook not support 320x240
but another browser and another OS can support it.

I want to know why. Please explain to me.

Answer (score 4):

This is [bug 1286945](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1286945). Firefox doesn't yet support downscaling of camera resolutions to constraints.

This means Firefox offers native camera modes only at the moment.

#### Workaround

Remove the `max` constraint on width and height. `min` and `max` are strictly enforced and are causing the *OverconstrainedError* here.

They're also largely unnecessary since the `ideal` value has gravity. So don't use them unless you're prepared to handle errors and try again with a fallback.

The browser should already find you the resolution closest to the ideal.

Read more about constraints [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#parameters).